# Django Filtering results inside ManyToManyField

Tags: django, serialization, model, django-rest-framework

I need to filter the results of a ManyToManyField before serializing it.

Example:

A user should see details on a record only if 'expiration_date' hasn't passed for 'Authorized Program' on file for the 'Individual' who is the subject of the record.

My model and serializer currently show a list of ALL related Authorized Program records.

**Question:**

**How can I filter that list to only non-expired records before returning as a list in the parent 'individual' record?**

*Note:
This is not a question about filtering the parent queryset based on the M2M field.  It's about filtering the contents of the M2M field before returning the parent.*

Currently, the serializer simply skips the 'active_authorized_program_list' field.

```python
class Individual(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default='')
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    authorized_program_list = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Program',
        related_name='individual_authorized_program_list',
        through='ReleaseAuthorization',
        blank=True
    )

    @property
    def current_age(self):
        if self.dob:
            today = datetime.date.today()
            return (today.year - self.dob.year) - int(
                (today.month, today.day) <
                (self.dob.month, self.dob.day))
        else:
            return 'Unknown'

    @property
    def active_authorized_program_list(self):
        return (
            self
                .authorized_program_list
                .get_queryset()
                .filter(expiration_date__lte=datetime.Date())
        )

class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default='')
    individual_list = models.ManyToManyField(
        'individual.Individual',
        related_name='program_individual_list',
        through='hub_program.ReleaseAuthorization',
        blank=True
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ReleaseAuthorization(models.Model):
    individual = models.ForeignKey(
        Individual,
        related_name="release_authorization_individual",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    program = models.ForeignKey(
        Program,
        related_name="release_authorization_program",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    expiration_date = models.DateField()


class IndividualSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = (
            'name',
            'dob',
            'current_age',
            'authorized_program_list',
            'active_authorized_program_list',
        )
```

Serialized Result is missing the last line for 'active_authorized_program_list':

```
{
    "name": "Individual One",
    "dob": "1974-10-11",
    "current_age": 43,
    "authorized_program_list": [1,2,3]
}
```

Should also have:

```
"active_authorized_program_list": [1,2]
```

Comment: On which model is you `expiration_date`? Also your design by mutually defining the ManyToManyField is at least very uncommon (never seen it). Is there a reason for it? Is the model's app called `hub_program` or do you have 2 different `ReleaseAuthorization` models in different apps? Please show also this model.

Comment: @ascripter I have the M2M field defined in both models to make it slightly easier to get the related data whether from Individual or Program.  Defining in both makes them accessible in the same way, instead of the reverse being different syntax.

Comment: ReleaseAuthorization is the same model in the hub_program app for both Individual and Program.  I just neglected to remove "hub_program" from the second part of the example when simplifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify type of field in serializer as `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`:

```
class IndividualSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    active_authorized_program_list = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = (
            'name',
            'dob',
            'current_age',
            'authorized_program_list',
            'active_authorized_program_list',
        )
```

Also you can generate list in serializer directly using [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class IndividualSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    active_authorized_program_list = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = (
            'name',
            'dob',
            'current_age',
            'authorized_program_list',
            'active_authorized_program_list',
        )

    def get_active_authorized_program_list(self, obj):
        return (
            self
            .authorized_program_list
            .filter(expiration_date__lte=datetime.Date()).values_list('id', flat=True)
         )
```

Comment: Working from your first option, PrimaryKeyRelatedField worked. To get to the related model, I had to change the filter slightly to .filter(release_authorization_program__expiration_date__gte=datetime.date.today()).  Thank you!